# The text in input value doesn't show when using input type="number"

Tags: html, css, forms, performance, input

I would like to keep the input type as "number". So how to I get around this, if input type="number" only allows for numbers as value and not text.

This is what I'm trying to achieve:

```
<input type="number" name="amount" value="Other Amount">
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead value I would use placeholder

```
<input type="number" name="amount" placeholder="Other Amount">
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to achieve text input which just numbers allowed, you should do something like this:

```
<input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'>
```

you need to control which character is allowed to be pressed down